# ¿Cómo tratar una pregunta particionada?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Hay usuarios que tienen un problema, pero van haciendo preguntas parciales del problema sin alcanzar una solución real hasta la tercera, cuarta o hasta quinta pregunta.

Técnicamente no son preguntas duplicadas porque tratan de errores o problemas distintos, pero el código general se repite una y otra vez sin que el OP logre llegar a una solución real. Por ejemplo: Primero pide como hacer una serie de fechas, luego pide como concatenar esa serie de fechas, después como usar esa serie de fechas en una función, luego como solucionar un error que aparece al ejecutar todo su código, luego como aumentar la característica para generar un resultado ligeramente distinto, etc.

¿Debería reportarse como duplicada? ¿Debería de votar para cerrarse? ¿O simplemente dejar que sigan su curso?

Podría dar un ejemplo concreto, pero no quiero que se genere el efecto meta.

Comment: Las preguntas (sin saber cuales son) son todas validas si tratan sobre problemas distintas. Lo que puede estar pasando es que le estas escribiendo todo el codigo a un usuario que no se toma el trabajo de tratar de solucionarlo por si mismo. Si es un error atras de otro, seria mejor abandonarlo y que lo intente por si mismo.

Answer (score 3):

En principio debería dejarse que sigan su curso porque las publicaciones que se realizan son preguntas no se trata de un espacio para compartir código, de hecho, se pide que cada pregunta incluya toda la información relevante en la publicación misma de la pregunta, así que está bien que incluyan el código varias veces cuando cada publicación es una pregunta distinta...

sin embargo...

habría que preguntarse de si esto está ocurriendo porque se trata de "Problemas X y Y" (preguntan como usar X para resolver Y en lugar de preguntar cómo resolver Y)

P.D. Si se ha includo enl a pregunta un ejemplo mínimo y completo "no me imagino" (bueno en realidad sí) cómo podrían estarse presentando diferentes errores. Sería conveniente tratar cada "serie" de preguntas en los particular.

Comment: Precisamente parece tratarse de Problemas X y Y.